# How to view mapped drives in cmd or PS that are mapped via Logon script bat file

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

User have network shares/mapped drives mainly done by logon scripts bat files. It load a series of locations.

I am trying to see if there is a way to view the mapped drives via CMD/PS.

I have tried 'net use' it is only showing the drives that are mapped manually ( net use f: \**)

I know what the mappings are if I look at the logon bat file but Im looking to view it without having to look/find the file

Any ideas

Comment: [1] mappings are per-account. so you will only see the ones mapped by code running in that accounts session. ///// [2] what drives are not showing? how were they created?

Comment: Use WMI.  [Try this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-determine-which-drives-are-mapped-to-network-shares/)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment, you should be able to see them via `gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk`.
You may want to also check to see if what you're expecting to see shows up under
`gwmi Win32_Share` , or `gwmi Win32_Volume| select name, caption, filesystem, drivetype, label` .